# Display qr code image from formula field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, formula-field, image-formula, qr-code

I have this formula field that shows the generated qr code on the record detail page:

```
IMAGE('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://www.yahoo.com' ,'QR code to open yahoo')
```

I need to display this qr code in an lwc. Adding it as a text field shows the code above. Using IMG and setting the value as src doesn't work either.

js

```
@wire(getEval, { recordId : '$recordId' })
eDetails({ data, error }){
    if(data){
        this.nameOnCard = data.Name_on_Card__c;
        this.qrCode = data.QR_Code__c;
    }else if(error){
        console.log('ERROR ----- ', JSON.stringify(error));

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
                        <div class="slds-grid" >
                            <div class="slds-col slds-truncate">
                                <img src={qrCode}>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

****Update
From the console, I can see the value of qrCode is:

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=https://www.yahoo.com" alt="SQR code to open yahoo" border="0"/>
```

so it looks like it's ready to just work. . . no need to add to img tag as src. Problem is, it just displays the value above when I need it to render the HTML contained in qrCode.

Any ideas on how to display the actual qr code (like on the record detail page) in an LWC?

Comment: Have tired displaying the url as: `<img src={qrCodeUrl}>`? You have to wire the qrCodeUrl with the value from the formula field.

Comment: @arnoldjr - I just added some snippets. I think that's what you mean? That doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted the `IMAGE` function outputs an `img` tag, but you could extract both the `src` and `alt` attribute from that string via [substring(startIndex, endIndex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function:

```
alternateText;

@wire(getEval, { recordId : '$recordId' })
eDetails({ data, error }){
    if(data){
        this.nameOnCard = data.Name_on_Card__c;
        const srcStartIndex = data.QR_Code__c.indexOf('src="') + 5;
        const srcEndIndex = data.QR_Code__c.indexOf('"', srcStartIndex);
        this.qrCode = data.QR_Code__c.substring(srcStartIndex, srcEndIndex);
        const altStartIndex = data.QR_Code__c.indexOf('alt="') + 5;
        const altEndIndex = data.QR_Code__c.indexOf('"', altStartIndex);
        this.alternateText = data.QR_Code__c.substring(altStartIndex, altEndIndex);
    }else if(error){
        console.log('ERROR ----- ', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

Then in the template you could have:

```html
<div class="slds-grid" >
    <div class="slds-col slds-truncate">
        <img src={qrCode} alt={alternateText}>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to replace a couple of &amp; with &. I could then copy that URL and see the qr code when I pasted the URL in a browser. I still don't see anything in the lwc.

Comment: @mackmama what's now the string stored in `this.qrCode`?

Comment: `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://xxxxxx--xxx.sandbox.my.site.com/sap/s/?recordId=a4xxxxxx0Wjjk`

a little more than Yahoo.com but I wanted to make easier

Comment: this got me almost there . .  one more thing -  I needed to go to Setup/Security/CSP Trusted Sites and add: *.googleapis.com. I didn't see the error right away after I implemented @RubenDG's code

`Refused to load the image 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://xxxxxx--xxx.sandbox.my.site.com/xxx/s/?recordId=a2i3S0000xxxxxxxk' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: blob:`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, you could use `<img src={qrCodeUrl}>`. Here I put it together as a draft, but technically it should work.

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="QR Code" icon-name="action:scan_enabled">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-truncate">
            <img src={qrURLData}>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import QR_CODE from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.QRCode__c';

export default class LwcQRCodeDemo extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
qrCodeUrl;

get qrURLData(){
    if(this.qrCodeUrl){
        return this.qrCodeUrl;
    } else{
        return null;
    }
}

@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: [QR_CODE]}) handleDataRes(response){
    if(response){
        let qrCodeField = getFieldValue(response.data,QR_CODE);
        if(qrCodeField){
            let qrURL = qrCodeField.split('(')[1].split(',')[0].split("'")[1]; 
            this.qrCodeUrl = qrURL;
        }
        
    } else{
        console.log('Error within Wire');
    }
  }
}
```

You have to ensure you properly wire the data coming from your custom field and extract it using a split/regex or other JS string operation.

Result:

[image]

I've used my Trailhead account. Added a RecordPage LWC to display the QR Code on the Contact record page.

Comment: thank you. I'll try this and let you know asap