# Display html contained in js variable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, html5

I have a variable in my js file, let's say `myCode = "<h1>HELLO</h1>";`

myCode displays as `<h1>HELLO</h1>` in HTML. . . I want it to render the h1 tag and just display **HELLO**

Comment: Doing this may expose you to security concerns, depending on where this markup comes from. It is intentionally not supported or easy to do using LWC. If you only have a limited number of options, you could use multiple templates with conditional rendering.

Comment: @PhilW - so this is actually related to a question I posted about rendering an img tag from a formula field. Thought I'd try and simplify

[original question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/405528/display-qr-code-image-from-formula-field-in-lwc)

Comment: I noticed that question but did not read it.

Answer (score 1):

LWC sanitizes what's rendered in the page to prevent security risk, that's why the default behavior is to display it as text instead of as a markup element.

Anyway, since some third-party libraries may need to manipulate the DOM, the framework exposes the `lwc:dom="manual"` [directive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_directives)

**HTML**

```html
<div class="myClass" lwc:dom="manual">
 </div>
```

**JS**

```js
modifyDom() {
     const hello = '<h1>HELLO</h1>';
     this.template.querySelector('.myClass').innerHTML = hello;
}
```

If you want to just render some text, you should leverage [`lightning-formatted-rich-text`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) to pass HTML tags in your component markup via its `value` attribute.